# Python imaplib append is slow

Tags: python, python-2.7, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to migrate my companies IMAP server to a new Exchange server using pythons imaplib.
This is the first time I have even looked at mail protocols, and I'm still new to networking in general. I don't know much about IMAP at all, and have just got by through trial and error so far.

At the moment my python script functions. It connects to each mailbox using imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host,port) and then proceeds to download and upload each email individually using this loop.

```
    for num in msgs: #iterate over each messages id number
        data = From.fetch(num, '(FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822)')[1]
        print "Message {0}/{1}".format(cnt, totalmsgs)
        flags = " ".join(imaplib.ParseFlags(data[0][0]))
        date = imaplib.Internaldate2tuple(data[0][0])

        try:
            #add a copy of the message to the archive box specified above
            To.append(box, flags, date, data[0][1])  
        except Exception, e:
            "Could not migrate message ", cnt
            print e
        cnt += 1
```

After doing some rough time measurements using timedelta, I found the append command can take up to a minute to complete. Could anyone shed some light as to why it is this slow?

I've already added this line

```
To.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

as suggested elsewhere

Comment: Probably the remote server is slow?  Also, data[0][0] includes multiple fetch results in it.  The date is probably not being parsed like you expect.

Comment: I have tested the parsing of data[0][0] and it is returning the flags and date correctly, and the amount of time it takes is insignificant. It could be that the server is slow, though how would I test that?

Comment: Use tcpdump or wireshark to watch the TCP connection. In this case you don't care much about the data being sent, only about when it's sent. A minute per message is ridiculous, it should be subsecond. BTW, there are existing programs to do this, at least five different ones when I investigated. I ended up preferring imapsync.